# laravel | Typeahead : How to combine db fields for display and get selected record's id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, typeahead.js, laravel-5.4

I am trying to implement auto complete functionality into my `laravel 5.4` project and so far I have been successful in displaying only a single db field (first name). Here is the code

**routes**

```
 Route::get('test',array('as'=>'search','uses'=>'SearchController@search'));
 Route::get('autocomplete',array('as'=>'autocomplete','uses'=>'SearchController@autocomplete'));
```

**controller**

```
public function autocomplete(Request $request)
{
     $data = customer::select("first_name as name")->where("first_name","LIKE","%{$request->input('query')}%")->orderBy('first_name')->take(6)->get();
     return response()->json($data);
}
```

**view**

```
  <form method="POST" action="/home/customer/{{$id}}">
   {{ csrf_field() }} 
      <div class="input-group input-medium " style="float: right; padding-top: 3px; padding-right: 15px; ">
            <input type="text" class="typeahead form-control" required>
                   <span class="input-group-btn">
                         <button class="btn green-haze" type="submit"> <i class="fa fa-search"></i></button> 

                        </span>
      </form>
//js
<script type="text/javascript">
    var path = "{{ route('autocomplete') }}";
    $('input.typeahead').typeahead({
        source:  function (query, process) {
        return $.get(path, { query: query }, function (data) {
                return process(data);

            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

So I have two figure out two things:

1. The above code as of now only shows first_name as autocomplete suggestions
   I would like them to be in the format `id - first_name last_name`
2. I also want to fetch the selected users id from autocomplete so that I can pass it in my form action `/home/customer/{$id}`

I am new to javascript and jquery so I dont yet understand how to do this. Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're only getting the `first_name` is because you're only selecting the first name, `select("first_name as name")`, remove the select from the query and you'll be returned a collection with all of the fields

e.g.

```
$data = customer::where("first_name","LIKE","%{$request->input('query')}%")->orderBy('first_name')->take(6)->get();
```

Then within your javascript callback, `data` will have access to each of the records found and their fields.

EDIT

With Typeahead you define a callback so that you can use the data which is returned, e.g:

```
$('input.typeahead').typeahead({
    source: {
        groupName: {
            // Ajax Request
            ajax: {
                url: "{{ route('autocomplete') }}"
            }
        }
    },
    callback: {
        onResult: function (node, query, result, resultCount, resultCountPerGroup) {
            console.log(node, query, result, resultCount, resultCountPerGroup);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I have tried that but I get no suggestions if I change my query to select all fields, here the browser console error             
`bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: b.toLowerCase is not a function
    at b.matcher (bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js:1)
    at bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js:1
    at Function.grep (jquery.js:753)
    at b.process (bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js:1)
    at proxy (jquery.js:818)
    at Object.success (customer:5125)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at y (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.c `

Comment: I have updated my answer to try and help you with the typeahead side of things

Comment: I tried to use the callback in my function but I don't get any suggestions now.